# Effect of non-normal distribution on repeated measures 2 way ANOVA

Tags: distributions, anova, normal-distribution, normality-assumption

Part of a piece of university work requires me to talk about the effects of non-normal distribution on ANOVA. I'm fairly certain that having non-normal distributions in data increases your chances of a type 1 error. I'm just really struggling to find a paper which actually specifies this.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? I see nothing but statements up there. :P

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of non-normality. In general, ANOVA is conservative with skewed data. As far as references, there was an article by Donaldson in the late 1960's and I am sure there are more recent ones. You can investigate it yourself if you have a browser that lets you run unsigned applets here: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/tests_of_means/robust_sim.html. The video demo on that page show some information on this.

There is also this article: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.921.8875&rep=rep1&type=pdf